# How to extract date from datetime in C# without converting it into string?

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract date from date time field but in C# it is not helping me to do it without converting it to string.

This is my class:

```
public class Student_Info
    {
        public String Student_Name;
        public DateTime DateofBirth;
}

 Student_Info student = new Student_Info();
 student.Student_Name = "XYZ";
 student.DateofBirth = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-01-01");
 MessageBox.Show(student.Student_Name + "" + student.DateofBirth);
```

This is how I am setting the value.

My expected result is `XYZ 2019-01-01`

But I am getting `XYZ 1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM`

Need Help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `student.DateofBirth.Date` but that is not `c` code

Comment: A `DateTime` always has a time component. You can take its `Date` property to get *midnight* of that date; that's as close as you're going to get without using a date-only data type such as [NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime)'s `LocalDate`.

Comment: This seems like a formatting issue.  Just do `student.DateofBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`,  Note that `DateTime` does not include a format, just a value to specifiy a specific point in time.  The formatting comes in when you want to display a string representation or when parsing a string to a `DateTime`.

Comment: The DateTime has two pieces 1) The whole number of days from 1/1/01 and fractional part of the day which is the number of ticks (100ns a tick) per 24 hours.  The best way of seeing this is to use ToTicks() method on different times. I would use 1/1/1 12:00AM, 1/1/1 6:00AM, 1/1/1 12:00PM, and 1/2/1 12:00AM.

Comment: Also you might as well do `new DateTime(2019, 1, 1)` if you want to hard code the values versus parsing from a string.

Comment: The max number of ticks per day is 0xc92a69c000 which is 40 bits.  So the 24 MSBs represent the days.

Comment: What do you mean by *"without converting it to string"*? If you want to display the date in a message box, you *have* to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 4):

The `DateTime` struct **always** has a time component. There is a `Date` property that will mostly do what you asked, but even that has an implied time of midnight.

However, while the question text says this:

> without converting it into string?

the code sample **IS** implicitly converting to a string:

```
MessageBox.Show(student.Student_Name + "" + student.DateofBirth);
```

In which case there are a number of options:

```
student.DateofBirth.ToShortDateString()
student.DateofBirth.ToString("d") 
student.DateofBirth.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")) //German format. You can put any culture here you need.
student.DateofBirth.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
student.DateofBrith.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Just be careful here, because some of those rely on the operating system's date format, and users can configure that to do *really weird stuff* if they really want to.

You can also use any of these right in the `MessageBox` string:

```
MessageBox.Show($"{student.Student_Name}{student.DateofBirth:yyyy-MM-dd}");
MessageBox.Show(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1:d}", student.Student_Name, student.DateofBirth));
```

Finally, I get a little scared whenever I see someone wanting to create a date string resembling the ISO-8601 date format, as is the case here. There are plenty of legitimate reasons to do this. However, there is one common reason people want to do this that also happens to be *very bad*: SQL. If you're doing this so you can include it in an SQL command string, you're almost certainly doing something very wrong, and you need to take a step back and research parameterized queries before doing anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
MessageBox.Show(student.Student_Name + "" + student.DateofBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: Then may be he can use yyyy-mm-dd instead of d

Comment: You should edit your answer to say *that*. (Although at this point you'd just be repeating a more complete answer.)